# Pydantic - Unable to serialize/validate while using "Union" with "Field" in response_model

Tags: python, json, validation, serialization, pydantic

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Python version: 3.7.7
- Pydantic version: 1.4

I'm trying to make the `class TableSetting` as `BaseModel` and take it as `response body`. But seems like there are some validation or serialization errors in this class.
I guess it might be `Union` or `Optional[str]` that I ues but not sure.

Source code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Body, Path
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Union, Optional
from enum import Enum


app = FastAPI()


class Tableware(str, Enum):
    SPOON= "SPOON"
    FORK= "FORK"

class TableSetting(BaseModel):
    kitchen: Union[Tableware, Optional[str]] = Field(..., title="I am title")
    numberOfknife: int = Field(None, ge=0, le=4)

@app.post(
    "/{tableNumber}/provide-table-setting",
    response_model= TableSetting,    
)

def provide_table_setting(
    *,
    tableNumber: str= Path(...),
):
    results = {"tableNumber": tableNumber}
    return results
```

The json schema of `class TableSetting` should look like this

```
TableSetting{
    kitchen*        I am title{
                        anyOf ->    string  
                                    Enum:
                                        [ SPOON, FORK ]
                                    string
                    }
    numberOfknife   integer
                    maximum: 4
                    minimum: 0
}
```

While performing `curl`

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/2/provide-table-setting" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

it return errors as follows with **response code 500, Internal Server Error** , seems like some there are some validation problems with `kitchen` but I can't figure out why.

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53558 - "POST /2/provide-table-setting HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/*****/miniconda3/envs/fastAPI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 385, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
.
.
.
  File "/home/*****/miniconda3/envs/fastAPI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 126, in serialize_response
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for TableSetting
response -> kitchen
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

However, when remove `= Field(..., title="I a title")` from the code as follows. It's works fine with a **response code 200**, but since I need `Item kitchen` as required, so it's not what I want.

```
class TableSetting(BaseModel):
    kitchen: Union[Tableware, Optional[str]]
    numberOfknife: int = Field(None, ge=0, le=4)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

according to the doc [Union](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions) it's accept different type , but not both,
instead of this you should use tuple with (required, optional)
something like that

```
from typing import Optional, Tuple
class TableSetting(BaseModel):
    kitchen: Tuple[Tableware, Optional[str]] = (None, Field(..., title="I am title"))
    #kitchen: Union[Tableware, Optional[str]] 
    numberOfknife: int = Field(None, ge=0, le=4)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it seems like trigger other errors 

----
File "pydantic/json.py", line 59, in pydantic.json.pydantic_encoder
TypeError: Object of type 'FieldInfo' is not JSON serializable
----

Any ideas?

Comment: can you send you curl cmd?

Comment: Sorry, you are right!  It's seems like the swagger UI not able to display it, but API was able to response normally.

"curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/2/provide-table-setting" -H  "accept: application/json"
"

Comment: Additionally, if SwaggerUI doesn't work, I've seen Redoc have much better support of `Union` and the like.